# Is there any shuffle mode in training Pytorch neural network model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I'm using the code below to train a simple neural net to learn a harmonic wave by PyTorch. But I want to turn the shuffle mode on to improve the model. Is there any syntax to this aim?

```
model = FCN(1,1,50,4)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=15e-3, weight_decay=15e-3/4000)

for i in range(4000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    yhh = model(x_data)
    loss = torch.mean((yhh-y_data)**2)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Also, I used the code below alternatively to reorder the learning set randomly, but the result was awful.

```
yhh = model(x_data[[np.random.choice(range(len(x_data)), len(x_data), replace=False)]])
```

Comment: Where is `x_data` coming from in your example? Your best option is to use a dataset with data loader which comes with this type of feature (randomizing the content of the items) by default.

Comment: @Ivan `x_data` is linspace data that is the domain of a harmonic function. From 0 to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `x_data` is plain Torch tensor of size, say [100], you can use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` with `shuffle=True` to shuffle `x_data` after each epoch:

```
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_data)  # first create a dataset wrapping your tensor
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=bs, shuffle=True)  # specify your required batch size
```

`dataloader` object is now an iterable and can be used as:

```
for data in dataloader:
    model(data[0])  #data[0] is a tensor of size(bs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [SubsetRandomSampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler), example:

```
validation_split = .2
shuffle_dataset = True
random_seed= 42

dataset_size = len(dataset)
indices = list(range(dataset_size))
split = int(np.floor(validation_split * dataset_size))

if shuffle_dataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
train_indices, val_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)
```

Note: `dataset` is a custom dataset that implements:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
def __len__(self):
    pass
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    pass
```